# INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED only on some devices

Tags: android, api, installation, google-play, monogame

My Android app fails to install on some “random”, older API devices (anything less than API level 25) with the error:

```
INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED
```

So, basically it seems… API < 25 ? MALFORMED : GOOD

I've seen similar questions where the answer has to do with a lowercase package name. I already have that.

Has anyone got any ideas?

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="128" android:versionName="1.2.8.0" package="com.vrgamestudio.thegame" android:targetSandboxVersion="2" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="29" />
    <application android:isGame="true" android:label="@string/ApplicationName" android:icon="@drawable/GameThumbnail" android:theme="@style/Theme.Splash">
        <activity android:name="TheGame.ActivityMain" android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true" android:launchMode="singleInstance" android:screenOrientation="fullSensor" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize|screenLayout">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="TheGame.ActivityTV" android:icon="@drawable/gamethumbnail" android:theme="@style/Theme.Leanback" android:banner="@drawable/banner320x180" android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true" android:launchMode="singleInstance" android:screenOrientation="fullSensor" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize|screenLayout">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.gamepad" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.faketouch" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.television" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback_only" android:required="false" />
</manifest>
```

BTW I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and MonoGame 3.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved and posted the answer here:

https://community.monogame.net/t/install-parse-failed-manifest-malformed-only-on-some-devices

In short the answer is:

On older api versions (<25 and therefore you should ALWAYS do this to support them?) it seems Android requires that:

> the fully qualified Namespace of the Activity Name property must be
> lowercase.